# VisualizeMonocularPlaneVisualOdometryApp boofcv calibration

Tags: java, camera-calibration, boofcv

I want run VisualizeMonocularPlaneVisualOdometryApp.How I get calibration file?If I use the boofcv's application to calibrate but I get a different file from mono_plane.yaml.
In particular, I don't have this part:
plane_to_camera:
rotation:

- 0.9999732346484106
- 0.007304326750623114
- 4.204729657194234E-4 ......

How do I solve?
Thank you in advance